# Convert Epoch value into 12 hours format timestamp

Tags: java, scala, epoch

I'm trying to convert Epoch time to Timestamp in Scala.

**Epoch Value** : 1475596740

**TimeStamp** : 1475596740*1000 => 1475596740000

The result timestamp always gives the result in 24HRs format.But i want to convert it to 12 hours format  in java/Scala.I used the following code

```
   val outputformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa");
    val formatteddTS = outputformat.format(ts)
    println(outputformat.parse(formatteddTS).getTime)
```

I need to compare this result to another timestamp value which is in 12 hours format. If i do the comparison the result is wired.

**Time 1 (Epoch)**

2016-10-04 21:29:00.0

1475596740000 (In milliseconds)

**Time 2 (Timestamp in 12 hours format)**

2016-10-04 09:29:28.0

1475553568000(In milliseconds)

**Result**

time2-time1 => **-43172**

Logically the time difference between 2016-10-04 21:29:00.0 and 2016-10-04 09:29:28.0 is about 28 seconds (28000) but the result I have got is 43172

Comment: You should be seeing an `AM` or `PM` at the end of a 12 hour format.

Comment: yes That is happening. but if i convert it to milliseconds, then the value remains same.

Comment: So are you saying to don't want them to be same.

Comment: @mhasan Logically  the time difference between 2016-10-04 21:29:00.0 and 2016-10-04 09:29:28.0 is about 28 seconds (28000) but the result I have got is 43172

Comment: I am just gonna leave it here for anyone who is looking at it. The difference is not 28 seconds, it's about 11.99hours.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is something wrong with your calculation because I can see the correct result with data you provided

```
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    long time1 = 1475596740000l;
    long time2 = 1475553568000l;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa");
    cal1.setTimeInMillis(time1);
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal1.getTime()));
    cal2.setTimeInMillis(time2);
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal2.getTime()));
    System.out.println(time1 - time2);
```

And the output:

```
2016-10-04 10:59:00 PM
2016-10-04 10:59:28 AM
43172000
```

43172000 is around 12 hours as it should be

EDIT

Ok, I've used another way as you proposed and result is the same again - 43172000:

```
    String date1 = "2016-10-04 21:29:00";
    String date2 = "2016-10-04 09:29:28 AM";
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date dateObj1 = null;
    Date dateObj2 = null;
    try {
        dateObj1 = format1.parse(date1);
        dateObj2 = format2.parse(date2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(dateObj1.getTime() - dateObj2.getTime());
```

And for "2016-10-04 09:29:28 PM" it returns -28000. I believe the problem is somewhere in date conversion

Comment: 2016-10-04 21:29:00.0 ,2016-10-04 09:29:28.0 convert this string to date and getTime() from them and do difference. then you can understand what  i mean.

Comment: Logically the time difference between 2016-10-04 21:29:00.0 and 2016-10-04 09:29:28.0 is about 28 seconds (28000) but the result I have got is 43172